# How to use Select query in encode decode function postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have checked on web I got one example like

```
select convert_from(decode(encode('abc', 'base64'), 'base64'), 'UTF8');
```

now I want to decode my string so I am trying the same with below mentioned

```
select convert_from(decode(encode((select resumestring from submitapplications where id=1030), 'base64'), 'base64'), 'UTF8');

ERROR:  function encode(text, unknown) does not exist
```

LINE 1: select convert_from(decode(encode((select resumestring from ...

Comment: Do you want actually decode or encode? What kind of data does your table contain? Add the table definition and some sample data to the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
    convert_from(
        decode(
            encode(
                convert_to(
                    (
                        select resumestring from submitapplications where id=1030
                    ),
                    'UTF-8'
                ),
                'base64'
            ),
            'base64'
        ),
        'UTF8'
    )
```